# Two coloured plane

Tags: triangles, combinatorial-geometry

Can you prove that For any two angles $θ,ϕ$  there exists a monochromatic triangle that has angles $θ,ϕ,180−(θ+ϕ)$ in two coloured plane?

Comment: Have a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/33832/monochromatic-triangles-in-every-two-coloring-of-the-plane and let us know what light the reports there shed on your question.